# swiftui ScrollViewReader scrollTo not correct working

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-scrollview, scrollviewreader

I am developing an application with swiftui. After zooming, when I say scroll to the corner with the ScrollViewReader, it goes out of the screen. my code is below. It fails after trying a few times. it doesn't do it every time.

```
 import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var zoomIn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            ScrollViewReader { reader in
                
                ScrollView([.horizontal,.vertical], showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< 11, id:\.self) { row in
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                ForEach(0 ..< 11, id:\.self) { column in
                                    Text("Item \(row) \(column)")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .frame(width: zoomIn ? 70 : 35, height: zoomIn ? 70 : 35)
                                        .background(Color.red)
                                        .id("\(row)\(column)")
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            withAnimation {
                                                reader.scrollTo( ["00", "010","100","1010"].randomElement()!)
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Button("Zoom") {
                        withAnimation {
                            zoomIn.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

my home screen.

[image]

after scrollTo

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is that the 2 `ForEach` just don't seem to work well with the `ScrollReader`. I took a different approach and used an identifiable struct and a `LazyVGrid`. That allowed me to use one `ForEach` and id the individual squares with a `UUID`. I then used the same `UUID` in the `scrollTo()`. The only difficulty I ran into was that `ScrollReader` didn't know what to do with a bidirectional `ScrollView`, so I made a function that returned the `UnitPoint` and used that as an anchor in the `scrollTo()`. That seems to have done the trick and it works very reliably.

```
struct BiDirectionScrollTo: View {
    
    let scrollItems: [ScrollItem] = Array(0..<100).map( { ScrollItem(name: $0.description) })
    
    let columns = [
        // Using 3 grid items forces there to be 3 columns
        GridItem(.fixed(80)),
        GridItem(.fixed(80)),
        GridItem(.fixed(80)),
        GridItem(.fixed(80)),
        GridItem(.fixed(80)),
        GridItem(.fixed(80)),
        GridItem(.fixed(80)),
        GridItem(.fixed(80)),
        GridItem(.fixed(80)),
        GridItem(.fixed(80))
    ]
    
    init() {
        
    }
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { reader in
            ScrollView([.horizontal,.vertical], showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(scrollItems, id: \.id) { item in
                        Text("Item \(item.name)")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                            .background(Color.red)
                            .id(item.id)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    if let index = [0, 9, 55, 90, 99].randomElement() {
                                        print(index)
                                        reader.scrollTo(scrollItems[index].id, anchor: setUnitPoint(index))
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func setUnitPoint(_ index:Int) -> UnitPoint {
        switch true {
        case index % 10 < 2 && index / 10 < 2:
             return .topLeading
         case index % 10 >= 7 && index / 10 < 7:
            return .topTrailing
        case index % 10 < 2 && index / 10 >= 7:
            return .bottomLeading
        case index % 10 >= 2 && index / 10 >= 7:
            return .bottomTrailing
        default:
            return .center
        }
    }
}


struct ScrollItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: It is nice. corners no problem. but this time it goes to the wrong places in the interior. for example the scroll index is 50 but it goes to 70. I don't understand why you did this? I just changed the frame to 300 and let index = Array(0..<(10*10)).randomElement()

Comment: It is an example based on your question. If you want something in the center, just add a case for it in the 'setUnitPoint' function. You can see how it is done. That is why I set the `default` to `.center` to handle the middle cases, but I didn't really code for them in the `switch`. I just divided the view into quadrants, but if you make those more toward the edge, the `.default` will take over for the middle.

Comment: I changed all of them to center. scrolls to irrelevant places. There is no problem in the code, why is this happening? I tried it on ios 15 iphone 13 similator and ipad pro 12.9 ios 15 similator. same result

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to get it to center as well. I think the issue is, if you changed ALL of `func setUnitPoint` to `.center`, you are telling it to try to put the corners in the center which doesn't work. Instead, you need to determine whether one of your squares is in the center, or in a corner, and go there. If you look in the updated `func setUnitPoint()` you can see I changed the test for what makes a corner. You can also add similar tests to make it hit a side. I did not over all cases. You need to decide what cases you want to cover yourself.

Comment: I made a mistake while converting rows and columns :( it's working perfectly now. thank you very much @Yrb

Comment: ios 15 scroolview has bug. this solution fixed bug thanks