# Controlling both horizontal and vertical scrollview position in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a `LazyVGrid` of views within a `ScrollView`, one of which is 'selected'. The user can move the selection by tapping up/down/left/right buttons. I am using a `ScrollViewProxy` to change the `ScrollView`'s position so that the selected view is always on screen. However in my attempts the `ScrollView` only scrolls up and down, and not left and right in response to change of `selectedCell`:

```swift
struct ScrollControlIssueDemoView: View {
    
    let columnCount = 6
    let rowCount = 20
    var numberOfCells: Int { columnCount * rowCount }
    var cells: [Int] { (0..<numberOfCells) .map { $0 } }
    let cellSize: CGFloat = 100
    var columns: [GridItem] { Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(cellSize), spacing: 0), count: columnCount) }
    @State private var selectedCell = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Left") { changeSelection(by: -1) }
            Button("Up") { changeSelection(by: -columnCount) }
            Button("Down") { changeSelection(by: columnCount) }
            Button("Right") { changeSelection(by: 1) }
        }
        ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
            ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(cells, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                            .frame(width: cellSize, height: cellSize)
                            .background($0 == selectedCell ? .red : .clear)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedCell) {
                Task {
                    scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(selectedCell, anchor: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func changeSelection(by delta: Int) {
        // Basic implementation for issue demo - I know it doesn't handle end of row correctly
        let newSelection = selectedCell + delta
        
        if newSelection > 0 && newSelection < numberOfCells {
            selectedCell = newSelection
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this code work?

Comment: Is there any reason why you use Task for scrolling. IMO its totally unnecessary

Comment: You are correct: I had found some advice that this might be the issue, and was testing it, but it doesn't make a difference - well in the simulator at least. Forgot to take it out of this demo code.

Comment: This seems to be the closest solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70177677/16157878

Comment: It's the other "task": [task(id:priority:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(id:priority:_:)).  Use `.task(id: selectedCell)` instead of `.onChange...`

Comment: Hmm - unfortunately doesn't work reliably in arbitrary sized grids.